How to "soft reset" the UConnect to fix audio issue on a 2021 Grand Cherokee (WK)?
I have a 2021 Grand Cherokee (the "old" platform). The audio just started acting up - distorted sound from any/all sources (including VR prompts). I've seen some suggestions on Jeep forums to resolve the problem by pulling a specific fuse to remove power from the UConnect, but it applies to a slightly older model JL (Wrangler). The identified fuse (F97) doesn't make sense when I look it up in my owner's manual, and the forum advice includes a picture of the PDC; mine looks quite different - I would have thought they would be largely similar.
So my question is: which is the appropriate fuse on my car, and should it be as simple as pull the fuse, wait a little while, plug it back in and off I go?
UPDATE
The problem seems to have resolved itself. The issue survived an engine stop/start cycle as well as being parked for about a half-hour or so, but after being parked overnight, the problem has disappeared. It would still be helpful to identify a more immediate correction than "park it overnight".
